# Cloud Run Container not connecting to Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have an application deployed via Google Cloud Run and I am trying to connect this to a Cloud SQL instance but it fails with the error 'OperationalError: connection to server at "12.345.678.901", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out'. "12.345.678.901" is the arbitrary public IP of the SQL instance.  I added my local IP to the SQL instance firewall and I can access the database from my local machine. However, I cannot access it from the cloud run instance as that does not come with an IP address. I followed the basic setup of the SQL instance, the only thing I did different is change the Cloud SQL connection string to the string provided by the running SQL instance. Is there a configuration im missing?

Comment: Are you using Cloud SQL Proxy?  Have you seen this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run)?

Comment: Why do you access directly the Database public IP and not to use the Cloud SQL connector of Cloud Run (@GlenYu comment)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I do not understand what you mean. Please clarify

Comment: In your code, you seam using the Cloud SQL public IP. My question is: why don't you use the Cloud SQL integration on Cloud Run? It's dedicated to your use case. Except if you have some constraints.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using Java, Go, Python, or Node.js, we have a corresponding connector that makes this easier. See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-connectors for details.